# Numpy matrix multiplication of 2d matrix to give 3d matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have two numpy arrays, like

```
A: = array([[0, 1],  
            [2, 3],  
            [4, 5]])   

B = array([[ 6,  7],  
           [ 8,  9],  
           [10, 11]])
```

For each row of A and B, say Ra and Rb respectively, I want to calculate transpose(Ra)*Rb. So for given value of A and B, i want following answer:

```
array([[[ 0,  0],  
        [ 6,  7]],  

       [[ 16,  18],  
        [ 24,  27]],  

       [[ 40,  44],  
        [ 50,  55]]])
```

I have written the following code to do so:

```
x = np.outer(np.transpose(A[0]), B[0])
for i in range(1,len(A)):
    x = np.append(x,np.outer(np.transpose(A[i]), B[i]),axis=0)
```

Is there any better way to do this task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use extend dimensions of `A` and `B` with [`np.newaxis/None`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) to bring in [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for a vectorized solution like so -

```
A[...,None]*B[:,None,:]
```

**Explanation :** `np.outer(np.transpose(A[i]), B[i])` basically does elementwise multiplications between a *columnar* version of `A[i]` and `B[i]`. You are repeating this for all rows in `A` against corresoinding rows in `B`. Please note that the `np.transpose()` doesn't seem to make any impact as `np.outer` takes care of the intended elementwise multiplications.

I would describe these steps in a *vectorized language* and thus implement, like so -

1. Extend dimensions of `A` and `B` to form `3D` shapes for both of them such that we keep `axis=0` aligned and keep as `axis=0` in both of those extended versions too. Thus, we are left with deciding the last two axes.
2. To bring in the elementwise multiplications, *push* `axis=1` of A in its original 2D version to `axis=1` in its `3D` version, thus creating a singleton dimension at `axis=2` for extended version of `A`.
3. This last singleton dimension of `3D` version of `A` has to align with the elements from `axis=1` in original `2D` version of `B` to let `broadcasting` happen. Thus, extended version of `B` would have the elements from `axis=1` in its 2D version being pushed to `axis=2` in its `3D` version, thereby creating a singleton dimension for `axis=1`.

Finally, the extended versions would be : `A[...,None]` & `B[:,None,:]`, multiplying whom would give us the desired output.

Comment: How can I do similar thing for 2 theano matrix ?

Comment: @Shweta AFAIK `theano` also supports `broadcasting`, so I would think this should work as it is for theano arrays/matrices too, won't they?

Comment: i was also thinking the same, so tried following:
y = T.dmatrix('y')
x = T.dmatrix('x')
z = x[...,None]*y[:,None,:]
But this is throwing error. Should I do something else, to make it work.

Comment: AsTensorError: ('Cannot convert Ellipsis to TensorType', <type 'ellipsis'>)

Comment: @Shweta Hmm I am not really familiar with how theano works, but I do know that they support broadcasting. Make a separate question out of it? Someone who is acquainted with theano might have better pointers to help you out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102400/discussion-between-shweta-and-divakar).

Comment: @Shweta Added some explanation here as requested. That took me a while to put all the thoughts applied to solve it :)