# Theano matrix multiplication of 2d matrix to give 3d matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, theano

I want to do exactly what the following question is trying to do in numpy:
[Numpy matrix multiplication of 2d matrix to give 3d matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35162197/numpy-matrix-multiplication-of-2d-matrix-to-give-3d-matrix/35162306?noredirect=1#comment58044934_35162306)

I have written the following code (as per the suggestion for numpy case), assuming that broadcast works in theano as well:

```
y = T.dmatrix('y')
x = T.dmatrix('x')
z = x[...,None]*y[:,None,:]
```

But it is throwing following error:

```
AsTensorError: ('Cannot convert Ellipsis to TensorType', <type 'ellipsis'>)
```

Comment: Or try `x[:,:,None]*y[:,None,:]`. That `x[...,None]` is a shorthand notation/way for `x[:,:,None]`.

Comment: There's an open issue on the Theano tracker: https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/2487

Comment: @Divakar, it is working... awesome!!! thanks

Comment: @Shweta Nice! So, post an answer with that comment as the solution code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Divakar s comment, change it to

```
x[:,:,None] * y[:,None,:]
```

Just posting it as an answer so that people know there's an answer to this.