# Element-wise multiplication of 'slices' of 2D matrix to form 3D matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

A matrix multiplication like this

[image]

Is easy to implement in Python using `numpy`

```
import numpy as np
np.array([[1, 2, 3]]) * np.array([[1], [2], [3]])

array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

But in my situation, I have 2 2D matrices that I want to multiply to form a 3D matrix. Effectively, the first 'slice' of the 2D matrix is an array that I want to multiply by the first 'slice' of the second matrix to form a 2D matrix. This is continued for all the 'slices' of the 2D matrices. Think of the first as being dimensions `[x,z]` and the second being dimensions `[y,z]`. I want to multiply them to get `[x,y,z]`. Is there an elegant way to do this in `numpy`?

Comment: What decides how many 2D slices you want in the final 3D, which is 3 for the sample? Or is that a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can already describe your multiplication as

```
[x, z] * [y, z] -> [x, y, z]
```

the most straightforward solution will most likely be using Einsum:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(12).reshape(4, 3)
# array([[ 0,  1,  2],
#        [ 3,  4,  5],
#        [ 6,  7,  8],
#        [ 9, 10, 11]])
B = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
# array([[0, 1, 2],
#        [3, 4, 5],
#        [6, 7, 8]])

C = np.einsum('xz,yz->xyz', A, B)
# array([[[ 0,  1,  4],
#         [ 0,  4, 10],
#         [ 0,  7, 16]],
# 
#        [[ 0,  4, 10],
#         [ 9, 16, 25],
#         [18, 28, 40]],
# 
#        [[ 0,  7, 16],
#         [18, 28, 40],
#         [36, 49, 64]],
# 
#        [[ 0, 10, 22],
#         [27, 40, 55],
#         [54, 70, 88]]])
```

An alternative is to simply use broadcasting

```
D = A[:, None, :] * B[None, :, :]
np.allclose(D, C)
# True
```

Comment: Wow, there is a function that matches exactly my mental model of the problem! Thanks @nilswerner

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out with the help of the response to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35162197/numpy-matrix-multiplication-of-2d-matrix-to-give-3d-matrix/35162306?noredirect=1#comment58044934_35162306).

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3]])
arr * arr.T

array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [3, 6, 9]])

mat = np.repeat(arr, 3, axis=0)
mat

array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])

mat[:,:,None] * np.transpose(mat[:,None,:], axes=(1, 0, 2))

array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [2, 4, 6],
        [3, 6, 9]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [2, 4, 6],
        [3, 6, 9]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [2, 4, 6],
        [3, 6, 9]]])
```

Comment: Think you can just do - `np.repeat( (arr * arr.T)[None],3,axis=0)` or `np.tile( (arr * arr.T)[...,None],3).T`.